# Creating new date using Javascript gives Invalid Date in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating a new date object in Javascript and it throws Invalid Date error in IE11.

It runs fine on Chrome and Firefox though.
Any idea what can be wrong?

```
new Date()
[date] Thu Sep 22 2016 12:24:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)[date] Thu Sep 22 2016 12:24:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[functions]
__proto__[date] Invalid Date
```

screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/hN4Kt8FEwdXu

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see that it throws? The console displays a Date instance. The `__proto__` property of this instance is an invalid date, but you should not care about that at all, it's part of the internal implementation.

Try `new Date().toString()`, you should get a valid string representation of your date, which means that all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It actually returns a date object where as the `__proto__` (prototype) alone says "Invalid Date" which is as per the ES5 Date specification which goes like this,

***The Date prototype object is itself a Date object (its [[Class]] is "Date") whose [[PrimitiveValue]] is NaN.***

**Source URL** : http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5

Hope this helps